# Extract all the rows of a particular field from nested JSON data using Javascript

Tags: json

I am trying to fetch the data entered by the user in Kendo Spreadsheet.
At present I am able to fetch the JSON data of the spreadsheet. 
But the JSON includes other data like the style attributes as well.
I want only the values or text in the cells.

```
 var spreadsheet = $("#spreadsheet").data("kendoSpreadsheet");
                            var sheet = spreadsheet.sheetByIndex(0);
                            var data = sheet.toJSON();

                            var rowCount = data.rows.length;
                            var jsonArray = [];
                            debugger;
```

var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)

```
for (var i = 0; i < rowCount ; i++) {


            jsonArray.push(JSON.stringify(data.rows[i].cells, null, 2));
                            }
```

This will give the JSON as

```
{
   "name":"Members",
   "rows":[
      {
         "index":0,
         "cells":[
            {
               "value":"Name",
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":0
            },
            {
               "value":"ID",
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":1
            },
            {
               "value":"Total",
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":2
            },
            {
               "value":"Dec2019_Data",
               "index":3
            },
            {
               "value":"Jan2020_Data",
               "index":4
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "index":1,
         "cells":[
            {
               "value":"NewMember",
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":0
            },
            {
               "value":240,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":1
            },
            {
               "value":200,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":2
            },
            {
               "value":100,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":3
            },
            {
               "value":100,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":4
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "index":2,
         "cells":[
            {
               "value":"Timo (718)",
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":0
            },
            {
               "value":150,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":1
            },
            {
               "value":400,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":2
            },
            {
               "value":300,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":3
            },
            {
               "value":100,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":4
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "index":3,
         "cells":[
            {
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":0
            },
            {
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":1
            },
            {
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":2
            },
            {
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":3
            },
            {
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":4
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

I want to exclude the attributes like "color":"#000000","enable":false etc.

I can get only the values by looping through the cells collection like this

data.rows[i].cells[0]["value"].

I wanted to know if there is a better way to do this.

At the end i want the cells to push only the "value" and "index" and exclude "enable","color" etc. 

"rows":[
      {
         "index":0,
         "cells":[
            {
               "value":"Name",         
               "index":0
            },
            {
               "value":"ID",             
               "index":1
            },
            {
               "value":"Total",        
               "index":2
            },
            {
               "value":"Dec2019_Data",
               "index":3
            },
            {
               "value":"Jan2020_Data",
               "index":4
            }
         ]
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hopefully this example dojo is what you are after: https://dojo.telerik.com/OxatiSax

All I have done is taken your json object and then using some sorting and mapping I have place the data in row order for you and then created an array of cell data array:

```
 [
    {
        "cells": [
            "Invoice #52 - 06/23/2015"
        ]
    },
    {
        "cells": [
            "ID",
            "Product",
            "Quantity",
            "Price",
            "Tax",
            "Amount",
            null
        ]
    },
    {
        "cells": [
            216321,
            "Calzone",
            1,
            12.39,
            2.478,
            14.868,
            null
        ]
    }]
```

so there is a lot going off here so let me explain.

Once you have got the "sheet as a json object" I first sort the rows based on their index:

which is done by this:

```
data.rows.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.index - b.index
})
```

You could add an additional check to ensure you have some rows but I have skipped that for the moment. So this function will compare the index of the rows and then sort them from 1 to n+1 order

Once we have the rows in the correct order we are only interested in the cells of each row.

This we can do with the `map` function so we iterate through each of the rows and check to make sure they have a cells collection and if so then we push the `cells array` to our main array again by using the map function:

```
.map((row) => {
      if (row.cells.length > 0) {
        celldata.push({
          cells: row.cells.map((cell) => {
            return cell.value;
          })
        });
```

so we assign the `cells` property an array of `cell.value` and then push this onto our `celldata` array.

if you simply wanted the cell values regardless of what row you wanted then you could just push the cells directly onto the array and have one giant collection of values in a single array.

If you need any further info on this let me know and I will update the answer accordingly.

**EDIT:**

For IE 11 support change the `arrow` functions to proper functions like so:

```
.map((row) => {
          if (row.cells.length > 0) {
            celldata.push({
              cells: row.cells.map((cell) => {
                return cell.value;
              })
            });
```

to

```
.map(function(row)  {
          if (row.cells.length > 0) {
            celldata.push({
              cells: row.cells.map(function(cell)  {
                return cell.value;
              })
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am using Kendo.mvc version 2016.2.504. When  i use the code above i am getting javascript error. I will try to upgrade to the latest kendo version and try. I will let you know if it worked.

Comment: I will try the above code after upgrading to the latest Kendo version (2019.2.619).

Comment: I tried the code after upgrading to 2019.2.619, the page does not load when the above code is present. It throws syntax error. at this line         
 data.rows.sort(function (a, b) { return a.index - b.index }).map((row) => {

Comment: are you able to provide your code as sample dojo? or provide the new code in your opening question so that I can see if there is a syntax error?

Comment: The solution works with the above code when Chrome is selected. But when IE11 is selected error is thrown

Comment: sorry. Here is an updated dojo https://dojo.telerik.com/OxatiSax/5 the reason it doesn't work in IE11 is because of the ES 6 arrow function which isn't supported in IE 11. I have also updated the answer to include the updated code for you

Comment: Is it possible to get the json like                                      "cells":[
            {
               "value":"Name" 
            },
            {
               "value":"ID"                
            },
            {
               "value":"Total"      
             },  "cells":[
            {
               "value":"John" 
            },
            {
               "value":"123"                
            },
            {
               "value":"0"      
             }]}   I need the "value" as the key so that i can deserialize the output to a datatable in C#

Comment: Yes all you need to do is change the value return section to return an object like {value:cell.value} then that will return each value like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hi found one more way using the map method as suggested by David Shorthose

```
var spreadsheet = $("#spreadsheet").data("kendoSpreadsheet");
                            var sheet = spreadsheet.sheetByIndex(0);
                            var data = sheet.toJSON();
                            var rowCount = data.rows.length;
                            var jsonArray = [];
                            var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
                            for (var i = 0; i < rowCount ; i++) {
                                var objs = data.rows[i].cells;
                                objs = objs.map(function (obj) {
                                    return { value: obj.value };
                                });

                                jsonArray.push(JSON.stringify(objs, null, 2));

                            }
```